# Markdown - Images with :colons:?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, atom-editor

Just a quick question, in the [Markdown Preview Package for Atom](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview) in the example screenshot, there seem to be images referenced by a keyword wrapped in colons <kbd>:</kbd> - why does this work? Couldn't find this syntax in the specifications of either normal Markdown or GFM ...

Comment: They seem to be not *images*, but rather Unicode emoticons referenced by name: [tada](http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/tada/index.htm), [fireworks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f386/index.htm). Presumably, there is some lookup table elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, ok. That explains it °ω°

Comment: It's not standard Markdown, this seems a [custom extension](http://blog.trello.com/emoji-and-markdown-everywhere/) for GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not images, those are Emojis

[Emoji cheat sheet](http://emoji-cheat-sheet.com)

Comment: Thank you, I was going nuts looking for this, there is nothing in the spec or cheatsheets about this